# How do we know that Quantum Mechanics isn't simply a theory of approximations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, quantum-interpretations, measurement-problem

From what I understand, QM is all about uncertainty. The wavefunction (or rather $|\Psi|^2$) gives us a probability of finding a particle at a certain point. Then, we measure the particle, and find what point it is at.

Now, here's my trouble - **QM states that before we measured this particle, it was in a superposition of many states and did not have a definite position.** This also implies the wave function is "perfect" because it gives as accurate information as possible about the position particle before we measure it.

So, how do we know this? Why can't there be a function $\phi$ that doesn't give probability distributions, but instead gives **definite locations** of particles, and we just haven't found a way of expressing or computing it? Why do we know that the position of particles is physically uncertain, and not just unknown to the experimenter? 
Sure, Quantum Mechanics works out beautifully and fits the results, but perhaps it is simply a very good theory of probability when we have a much more elegant and simple theory?

Comment: This sounds like hidden variables, which are found by Bell's Theorem and subsequent experiments to not be possible. I recommend reading the wikipedia page for this :) [Hidden variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_variable_theory)

Comment: Are you familiar with [De Broglie–Bohm theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Broglie%E2%80%93Bohm_theory)?

Comment: @Alubeixu, it's not true that Bell's Theorem shows 'hidden variable' theories are not possible, only that *local* hidden variable theories are excluded by experiment (and even this conclusion has a 'superdeterminism' loophole)

Comment: I *really* dont understand the downvotes to this question. Sure, the idea in the OP has been rejected by the scientific community, but that doesn't mean that the question is bad. The post is well-written, and the question is not silly.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform, a question may be well written and not silly and still not show any research effort.  I suspect that's the reason for the downvotes.

Comment: @AlfredCentauri To be honest, there was research effort, but not many results - googling this question is very tricky if you don't know the terminology (even putting it into words here was hard). The wiki page for hidden variables explains all of this, but I'll leave this up in case anyone else is having trouble finding reference on this problem.

Comment: TreFox, I'm just guessing on why anyone would down-vote but I do think it helps to put into a question at least some passing mention of what you've looked up here or elsewhere and tie that in with your question.  For example, see this similar question: [Is the Copenhagen interpretation merely an approximation to quantum mechanics?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/94675/9887)

Comment: I am closing this question as a duplicate, because the essentials ("how do we know QM isn't just a hidden-variable theory?") are so much of a well-trod ground on this site that this question should not go on the Hot Network Questions sidebar - it's just not constructive enough to be representative of this site, and to the extent that the topic is worthy of further discussion, this question is simply not couched in sufficient nuance to really advance that conversation. I'm reluctant to answer-then-close, but this one really doesn't deserve the spotlight.

Answer (score 11):

We don't. It could well be the case that there is a deeper theory than quantum mechanics which makes all or most of the weirdness go away. There's a lot of people looking for those kinds of theories and in the past eight decades they've mostly come up empty handed.

What we *do* have is strong constraints on how that theory can look like - things like the [Bell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem), [Kochen-Specker](https://freethoughtblogs.com/atrivialknot/2016/12/07/kochen-specker-theorem-explained/) or [PBR](https://freethoughtblogs.com/atrivialknot/2017/01/19/the-pbr-theorem-explained/) theorems, or the far-reaching effects of nonlinearities - which make it very hard for theories to do away with the weirdness and still reduce to quantum mechanics.

Thus it's perfectly possible for someone to come up with a theory that supersedes QM, and if they do then we will all thank them for it. However, from the way things are looking like right now, that bigger theory is likely to be even weirder than QM, and it is likely to force you to give up principles that we hold even more tightly than locality and realism, such as the possibility to set up independent experiments in different places. And, if you do go that far, then many physicists will begin to question just to what extent that theory is an improvement over the weirdness of quantum mechanics.

Comment: You link Bell's theorem to Wikipedia, and the two others to another site. But the site also has [a discussion of Bell's theorem](https://freethoughtblogs.com/atrivialknot/2016/12/04/bells-theorem-explained/). Maybe better link it too.

Comment: @Ruslan If you feel you can offer a better answer, you're welcome to post it. I have my reasons for linking as I did, but it appears (since you came in directly suggesting change, instead of asking questions) that you're not that interested in them.

Answer (score -2):

I'm my opinion, the best bet that your suggestion may be true is *Classical Stochastic Electrodynamics*.  This theory is not very well known, and still in its development phase.  But its ideas are very interesting.  See there :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_electrodynamics

https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.0916

In brief :  Stochastic Electrodynamics (SED) postulates that the vacuum is filled with zero-point fluctuations of the electromagnetic field, that can be described classicaly.  It's just a stochastic field that is there, isotropic, homogeneous, and have a Lorentz invariant spectrum.  Yet, this random field have an effect on the motion of particles, and the observer can only see some average behaviors.  This theory *suggest* that QM is a kind of *effective theory*, valid for some time and space averages only.  It can also reproduce most of the formalism of QM, but it's mathematically a very complicated theory.

The Planck constant enters that theory as a *classical constant* that defines the *scale* of the random field.  All (most ?) of QM follows from that.

Comment: Can I know why the down vote ?  I think this answer fits the OP query.

Comment: Maybe you should say some words about what CSE is and what drawbacks it has (nonlocality etc., maybe mentioning Bell's theorem). Otherwise it's mostly a [link-only answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it really looks like a crackpot theory. Unless it predicts something new that can be experimentally tested, I'd expect that theory to stay "little known".

Comment: @Magicsowon Bohm-de Broglie theory isn't considered crackpot theory (it's an interpretation of QM), and CSE, according to Wikipedia, is its extension.

Comment: Stochastic Electrodynamics is certainly not a "crackpot" theory.  The reason it isn't very well known yet is it's very complicated (non-linear), and it can only do numerical evaluations.  The calculations do reproduces most of the QM predictions.

Comment: @Cham most?.. and which not?

Comment: Most, because it isn't a finished theory yet.  And its calculations are complicated and need numerical solutions on powerfull computers. (damn typos !)

Comment: Does the theory predict anything new that can be checked experimentally?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I think it just offer a reinterpretation of QM (as a kind of *effective theory*), that restores the old classical concepts, causality, determinism, locality, etc.  It's often described as "non-local" for reasons not clear to me, but from the papers I have read, it's clearly a fully classical special relativistic theory.

Comment: To see why it's non-local, you should first learn about its predecessor, Bohm-de Broglie theory. It's an interpretation in the same spirit, but simpler due to not trying to reproduce QED, only QM.

Comment: From the papers I've read, SED is vaguely like Bohm-deBroglie theory.  Almost all papers on SED that I've read say nothing about that older theory.